# Invertible matrix and eigenvalue

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

- Let $A$ be an invertible matrix. If $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$, show that $\lambda\neq 0$ and that $\lambda ^{-1}$ is an eigenvalue of $A^{-1}$.

My proof trying. Assume $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$. Since $A$ is an invertible matrix, $Det(A)\neq 0$. Since $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$,

$Det(A-\lambda I_2)=0$. Let $A=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 \\ 3 & 4 \end{pmatrix}$.Thus, $Det(A)\neq 0$. Then, $Det(A-\lambda I_2)=\lambda ^2-5\lambda -2=0$. So, solution of this equation, $x_1,x_2= \dfrac {\pm5+4\sqrt {2}}{2}$. **Now, what should I do? Can you help, can you check my proof-trying?**

Comment: Since $det(A) \ne 0$ you have immediately that no eigenvalue is zero since the determinant is the product of eigenvalues.

Comment: For the second part you have $Ay=\lambda y \rightarrow \; y=\lambda A^{-1}y \rightarrow \; \lambda^{-1}y=A^{-1}y$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your proof is wrong, $A$ has to be *any* square matrix. Let $\lambda \neq 0$ be an eigenvalue of $A$, by definition $$Av=\lambda v,$$ where $v \neq \mathbf{0}$ is a vector. Multiplying by $A^{-1}$ both sides of the equation yields $$A^{-1}Av=A^{-1}\lambda v \iff v=A^{-1}\lambda v \iff \lambda^{-1}v=A^{-1}v.$$ Hence $\lambda^{-1}$ is a eigenvalue of $A^{-1}$.

Answer (score 0):

Since $det(A) \neq 0$, you know all eigenvalues are nonzero since the determinant is the product of the eigenvalues.

Now if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue with eigenvector $v$, then $Av=\lambda v$. Leftmultiplying by $A^{-1}$, you have $v=\lambda A^{-1} v$ or $\frac{1}{\lambda}v= A^{-1} v$ and you are done.

Comment: Thanks for answer.